# Access API in Nightwatch command

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm calling a section command in a test. The command tries to call

```
this.api.click('@someElement')
```

This results in a failing test with the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined.
```

I've also tried

```
this.click()
```

Which tells me

```
TypeError: this.click is not a function
```

Comment: As a follow up. I changed my command to just console.log(this) and used getLog in my test to see what's printed. It looks like 'this' is an empty object: '{}' is printed.

Comment: `browser.page.pageName.click('@pageElement)`

Comment: @hikaryu - thanks, but my question refers to using a command within a section. It turns out my syntax was correct but there was an error in my json that was not reported by Nightwatch.

Comment: Well, i thought u mean normal command, not a custom :)

Comment: please post block of code where you called this "section" command